# remove all properties with the same key name inside object

Tags: node.js, lodash

Let's say if my object looks something like this

```
{
  "success": true,
  "result": 1,
  "id": "123",
  "group": [
    {
      "id": "333",
      "label": "group 1",
      "students": [
        {
          "id": "s123",
          "name": "ying"
        },
        {
          "id": "s456",
          "name": "yang"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "888",
      "label": "group 2",
      "students": [
        {
          "id": "j123",
          "name": "yinga"
        },
        {
          "id": "j456",
          "name": "yanga"
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}
```

And I need to remove all the properties with the key "id".. means `id`s inside the root object, group and students need to be remove completely.

How can I do this in Node or lodash?

Comment: You wanna achieve to only ```{succsess : value, result: value }```?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lodash remove items recursively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085399/lodash-remove-items-recursively)

Comment: This answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/39087474/301584 works great

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```js
const myObject = {
  success: true,
  result: 1,
  id: "123",
  group: [
    {
      id: "333",
      label: "group 1",
      students: [
        {
          id: "s123",
          name: "ying"
        },
        {
          id: "s456",
          name: "yang"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: "888",
      label: "group 2",
      students: [
        {
          id: "j123",
          name: "yinga"
        },
        {
          id: "j456",
          name: "yanga"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
};

function removeKeyFromObject(keyToDelete, objectToParse) {
  if (!objectToParse) {
    return objectToParse
  }

  if (Array.isArray(objectToParse)) {
    return objectToParse.map(objectInArray => {
      return removeKeyFromObject(keyToDelete, objectInArray);
    });
  } else if (objectToParse && typeof objectToParse === "object") {
    if (keyToDelete in objectToParse) {
      delete objectToParse[keyToDelete];
    }
    const newObject = {};

    Object.keys(objectToParse).forEach(currentKey => {
      if (currentKey === keyToDelete) {
        return;
      }
      if (typeof objectToParse[currentKey] === "object") {
        return (newObject[currentKey] = removeKeyFromObject(
          keyToDelete,
          objectToParse[currentKey]
        ));
      }
      return (newObject[currentKey] = objectToParse[currentKey]);
    });
    return newObject;
  }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(removeKeyFromObject("id", myObject), null, 2));
```

Comment: I tried your code but I got the error ` TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'id' in null` that points to this line `if (keyToDelete in objectToParse)`

Comment: Try it now. Also, it would be helpful if you posted the actual data you are using. The data structure you pasted passed my code. Do you have the data structure you are actually using to run this against?

Answer (score 0):

```js
let data = {
  "success": true,
  "result": 1,
  "id": "123",
  "group": [
    {
      "id": "333",
      "label": "group 1",
      "students": [
        {
          "id": "s123",
          "name": "ying"
        },
        {
          "id": "s456",
          "name": "yang"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "888",
      "label": "group 2",
      "students": [
        {
          "id": "j123",
          "name": "yinga"
        },
        {
          "id": "j456",
          "name": "yanga"
        }
      ]
    },
  ]
}

let {id, ...prunedData} = {
  ...data,
  group: !!data.group ? data.group.map(g=>{
    let {id, ...withoutGroupId} = g
    return {
      ...withoutGroupId,
      students: !!g.students ? g.students.map(s=>{
        let {id, ...withoutStudentId} = s;
        return withoutStudentId;
      }) : null
    }
  }) : null
} ;

console.log(prunedData);
```

Comment: I tried your code but got the error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` which points to the line `group: data.group.map(g=>{`

Comment: it happens when ```group``` or ```students``` are not an array. You didn't mentioned they may be empty. i'll edit

Comment: Thanks but I already got the answer from the link above

Comment: @imin i did update it. Have a nice time and try to learn js/es.